# Watir-Webriver - Automating autocompletion field

Tags: autocomplete, watir-webdriver

Using Watir-webdriver I am trying to input an answer to a question that autocompletes as you type from a selection, I have searched all over the place for an answer but to no avail.

heres the snippet of code that i am trying to get some form of a id from so i can just inject into it ;)

```
<input type="text" data-bind="source: MultiOptionsList,events:{select:AutoSelect},value:     AutocomplateText" data-text-field="Value" data-role="autocomplete" class="form-input k-input" style="width: 100%;" autocomplete="off" role="textbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="" aria-busy="false">
```

Hope this makes sense, looking for something along the lines of "@browser.(:id => "blah").set "#{arg}""

Thanks Guys!

Comment: You should be able to set the text field like any other text field - ie using `.set`. If that did not work, you will need to give more details - ie what happens and what is not happening.

Comment: Thanks, Justin, I am about 15 pages into a very long application process and this one in particular is the only input that is not the same as all the others, I have had button clicks, tick boxes, radio buttons, text inputs and they all work perfectly well its just this particular text box that is different to the rest because as you type is starts to autofill with a set of answers to choose from, it has no ID for me to inject into- hope this makes sense. and thanks for your reply, as i cannot set ????(:id => "blah") as i do not know what blah is - hope this helps

Comment: Sounds like your first problem is being able to locate the text field on the page. Is this the only autocomplete control on the page - if so, you could locate the element by the data-role attribute. Otherwise, you will need to take a different strategy for finding the element, which is hard for us to help do without seeing the rest of the page. While my book ["Watirways"](https://leanpub.com/watirways) is largely in progress, you might find it helpful since it covers different strategies for finding elements.

Comment: I will look into the data-role attribute and yes this is the only autocomplete control used on the page, thanks again i will report back my findings! - also i will read through your book - thanks for the link ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that this is the only autocomplete control on the page and the text field does not have any descriptive attributes, you could locate the element by its data-role attribute:

```
browser.text_field(:data_role => 'autocomplete').set('some text')
```

Comment: However, you should really use an id because this will introduce potential brittleness into your tests.

Comment: Thanks Rogue, the code i am working off is very brittle as it is, lots of repeated id's and text field names used for just place holders at present, now i am faced with a button class that is used accross the application process but it something is not correct with this at present, what i plan to do is feed back to the devs all the issues i had in creating a simple automation test on this form snippet below

Comment: <button class="butt" data-bind="click: PersonClick">1Person (single user)</button>

Comment: there is another iteration of the application sign up coming today and i had quick look at the code and these has replaced all buttons, should not pose a problem - anyhelp on how to locate this with watir would be a great help i was thinking it would be somewhere along the lines of browser.button(:class => 'butt' :id =>PersonClick).click something along these lines - thanks again guys you rock!

Comment: It is hard to tell what is meant to actually be unique for that button, but `browser.button(:class => 'butt', :data_bind => 'click: PersonClick').click` or `browser.button(:class => 'butt', :data_bind => /PersonClick/).click` might work.

Comment: It worked perfectly, one issue i am seeing, is that steps that repeat like clicking a nextstep button or proceed button even though they have the exact same attributes, i updated my button click with    @browser.button(:class => 'butt' :data_bind => click: nextClick").wait_until_present and then the same with .click - it works for my previous screen that brings me my PersionClick issue which is resolved as i can see the selection being made, but the repeat step of And I click Proceed does not click the damn button o.0 - I have learnt loads and i cannot thank you enough ;)

Comment: Is the button reloading content via an asynchronous request or is it a full postback? Assuming the former, Watir might be trying to click the second button before the form has reloaded (ie it is clicking the same button twice). For this, you would want to look into using one of the wait methods.

Comment: i use wait_until_present before each .click, hmm any other wait methods you can think of?

Comment: oh its a full postback btw sorry.

Comment: Nothing else comes to mind. A working example that reproduces the problem would be useful.

Comment: I will see what i can do about putting this somewhere for you to access maybe. thank you!